# Check if user is logged in other device

Tags: php, mysql, session, timer

I have a website where people can login, logout etc. I want to make it possible to only log in on 1 device, so if you log in with same account on lets say your phone it will give an already logged in error or so.

So I've figured out to make a "online" table which I will update to 1 on logging in and browsing page for each user, but how would I make it a 0 when someone left the page without logging out? I heard someone talking about a MySQL timer function but how does that work? So that it will set online to 0 after 300 seconds inactivity or so.

Comment: You actually don't need a flag. You can only check the last_active time to decide if the user is logged in or not

Answer (score 1):

Normally you do this by updating a record in the database each time the user performs an action that indicates they're alive, or possibly via some kind of regular AJAX call that indicates they've at least got the page open.

It's generally of the form:

```
UPDATE users SET visited_at=NOW() WHERE id=?
```

Where you can provide the user's ID for that value based on the session information you have.

Comment: Oh really thanks I didn't think about it this way! I will try it.

Comment: Adding onto this, as it may not be super obvious, you can check if the time in the database is longer ago than some time of your choice (E.G 15 mins, 10 mins, etc), and if so, allow login. @ErikvanderWoning

Comment: There's some caveats here, like how users will often want to use this on multiple devices legitimately, as in hand-off the session from their phone to desktop or vice-versa, so try not to be super obnoxious about this limit, you'll just make people angry. You might want to set the threshold to 2 instead of 1 to handle these situations, but tracking multiple sessions can be a little trickier.

Answer (score -3):

As far as my understanding You can try to create a column "isLogged" in the database and set it to true or false.When the user starts or end a session.

Comment: Ye but how would you set it to false when someone just clicked browser away

Comment: in Mysql you can set the session time out .SET SESSION wait_timeout = 60